# Where are the access points for "Citadel: Batarian Codes"?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Jordan Noles asked me to help track the illegal use of Batarian codes on the Citadel. I accessed the Spectre terminal and enabled the tracking. According to my journal I now need to locate access points on the Citadel.

Where exactly are those access points located on the Citadel?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are 3 terminals that you must access in this order:

- Huerta Memorial Hospital - Lab Services waypoint
- Normandy Dock - Passenger Lounge waypoint
- Docks: Holding Area - Bay E28 waypoint.

Note that you can access your map and you'll see a "Terminal" called out under the waypoint  on the map - this indicates that there's something to interact with in this area.  By paging through the map, you can more easily locate your next objective.  The map doesn't discriminate between quests, however, so you might see items from multiple Journal entries at once.

Comment: You have to do it in the order listed, or it doesn't work.

Comment: @Bruce, yes, you are correct.  Sorry if that wasn't obvious, I'll make it moreso.

Comment: on my ps3 that waypoint is called console on the maps